# Google Maps - Online Map Marker to mark polygons and shapes onto the map

Tags: google-maps, mapping

I'm looking looking for a tool that will allow me to make a map exactly like this:
http://datasearch.uts.edu.au/about/mapsdirections/map.cfm

Basically I need to put shapes around buildings in the satellite view and then slap a marker and information window on them so that I can specify the building name and contents.

So the main issue is that I need the ability to draw shapes directly onto the maps as I don't fancy taking down the lat lng of each corner of the polygon.

Ideally what I'd like to do is have an online application that exports those points to KML, and then I would display google maps on my site and import that kml to display it.

Other suggestions welcome!

Jason

Comment: What do you mean by tool?You can use google maps javascript api v3

Comment: I mean to make shapes it's a major pain to specify the corners of each shape... is that not clear in my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a polygon creator

http://www.the-di-lab.com/polygon/

It's simple to use and allows you to copy and paste straight into your code. Would be nice if it had a button that said sent to kml though..